# JButton, JTextFeild, JLabel set background color not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel, jtextfield

This is my code for JButton. I am facing problem in setting background color for this Login button

```
JButton btnlogin = new JButton("Log in");
    btnlogin.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 14));
    btnlogin.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    btnlogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            EmailValidator emailValidator = new EmailValidator();
            if(!emailValidator.validate(txtEmail.getText().trim())) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Email ID");
                validationtext.setText("Invalid Email");
            }
        }
    });
    btnlogin.setBounds(210, 432, 200, 48);
    btnlogin.setBackground(new Color(66, 185, 217));
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnlogin);
```

I have already tried setting opaque value as true, but still not working.

Comment: For `JTextField` and `JLabel` you only need to set opaque as true.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks @SWETAKESUR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add two lines before setting background color to get your expected result:

1. Set opaque value as true by writing this : `btnlogin.setOpaque(true);`
2. By default a border is set in JFrame, you have to change it according to your wish. Here I am using example of MatteBorder : `btnlogin.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));`

Then after you will get your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This code actually changes the color of the button:

```
btnlogin.setOpaque(true);
btnlogin.setBorder(null);
btnlogin.setBackground(Color.red); // Any color you wish
```